# Angular 4 jwt authentication

Tags: angular, express, nodes, passport.js

Authentication using passport jwt from angular app
    I am setting my request  header in angular 4 as
    I am using passport jwt in server side but i  am getting unauthorized error

```
`let strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOpts, (jwt_payload, cb)=>{
    let stmt = "select * from user where id = ?";
    let id = jwt_payload.id;
    connection.query(stmt, id, (error, result) => {
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        if(result){
            var userinfo = {
                email: result[0].email,
                id: result[0].id
            }
            cb(null, userinfo);
        }
        else{
            cb(null, false);
        }
    })
})`

//this is my route
`app.use('/tournament',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), tour_route);` 


//This is my angular call
 createTournament(name: string){
        this.token = 'JWT ' + this.authService.getToken();
        const body = {
            name
        }
        this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/tournament',
            {
                headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.token)
            })
            .subscribe(
                response => {}
                );
    }

But i am getting an unauthorised access even if i am sending the right token
```

Comment: You have to add the relevant parts of your code otherwise nobody will be able to help you

Comment: I am guessing for some reason your token is not being fed into the "Authorization". I also don't get why your client side is adding "JWT" into your token when you are getting it from authService? The token sent to your Local Storage from backend should not be changed at all when you are getting it from the localStorage. Can you by any chance post your backend code such as app.post() or app.put() etc.

Comment: Have you checked that you're getting the token from this.authService.getToken() before making the request?
And It'll be helpful if you can add code that you've written to verify your token.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding Bearer or Token or Basic along with the Token, this should solve the issue.

headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+this.token)

Comment: add these to django settings                                     
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

Answer (score 0):

In case of backend, you have to pass "username" and "password" fields in the form of post method. Because PassportJS package will expected only username and password as a request data.

Then using **passport-jwt** package, you can generate token and pass that token in the request data of login API. After that from frontend, whenever you will make any call to the backend. then you need to pass that token with Header details. you can access then token user **req.headers** option and verify the token jwt.verify. if it will verfied then call **next()** function. SO that it will call next middle ware. Other wise, It will send error mesage to frontend